# uwsgi deployment using Emperor: Repeated "announcing my loyalty to the emperor"

Tags: perl, uwsgi, dancer

Using uwsgi running two psgi Perl Dancer apps.

Is it normal for uwsgi vassals to repeatedly announce their loyalty to the Emperor, upon nearly every request?

Here's a small portion of my uwsgi.log file:

```
announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
Mon Aug 17 20:51:59 2015 - [emperor] vassal www.ini is now loyal
[pid: 1713|app: 0|req: 4/11] 0.0.0.0 () {44 vars in 873 bytes} [Mon Aug 17 20:52:12 2015] GET /sitemap-index.xml => generated 284 bytes in 7 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 4 headers in 146 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
[pid: 1706|app: 0|req: 2/12] 0.0.0.0 () {42 vars in 808 bytes} [Mon Aug 17 20:52:22 2015] GET / => generated 113840 bytes in 207 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 4 headers in 143 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
[pid: 1709|app: 0|req: 1/13] 0.0.0.0 () {42 vars in 844 bytes} [Mon Aug 17 20:52:35 2015] GET /about => generated 124031 bytes in 1325 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 4 headers in 143 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
Mon Aug 17 20:52:36 2015 - [emperor] vassal www.ini is now loyal
[pid: 1713|app: 0|req: 5/14] 0.0.0.0 () {44 vars in 865 bytes} [Mon Aug 17 20:52:38 2015] GET / => generated 113840 bytes in 129 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 4 headers in 143 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

These announcements of loyalty to the Emperor appear to occur with nearly every request.

Are these poor vassals trying to kiss up to the Emperor for special favors, or (more likely) is there something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: They're still kissing up in December of 2019, lol

Comment: They still keep on doing it loyally.